# C++ Get country code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, geolocation, country

I'm trying to get the country code (example: "UK" or "SI" or "GER") via GetGeoInfo().

```
    GEOID GetUserGeoID(GEOCLASS_NATION);
```

Currently getting the value 16 from the above function ^ but looking in the table there's no number 16.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374073(v=vs.85).aspx

I know it's only 3-4 lines of code but I can't seem to figure it out on my own. Any help would be appriciated.

EDIT:

```
GEOID myGEO = GetUserGeoID(GEOCLASS_NATION);
int sizeOfBuffer = GetGeoInfo(myGEO, GEO_ISO2, NULL, 0, 0);
WCHAR *buffer = new WCHAR[sizeOfBuffer];
int result = GetGeoInfo(myGEO, GEO_ISO2, buffer, sizeOfBuffer, 0);
```

Got it to display my country number but I don't know how I'd transform it into an ISO code.

Comment: Post all 3-4 lines of code?

Comment: Does it gives you `16` or `0x16` ? (which is the Bahamas btw)

Comment: @Thomas It gives me 16 not 0x16.

Comment: Well, that's weird because GEOCLASS_NATION == 16

Comment: @Thomas Do you know how I'd get the country name? I can trim it down or something.

Comment: Could you include a bit more of your code, it would help me to help you

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting in comment, it'll be easier for others :)

Comment: @Thomas I've edited the main question.

Comment: Sorry, but you should have the iso code in `buffer`.  Can you check with `wcout << buffer;` what you get ?

Comment: @LenovoGlass you're welcome ! I think you should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to understand when to use cout and when wcout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the country ISO:

```
GEOID myGEO = GetUserGeoID(GEOCLASS_NATION);
int sizeOfBuffer = GetGeoInfo(myGEO, GEO_ISO2, NULL, 0, 0);
WCHAR *buffer = new WCHAR[sizeOfBuffer];
int result = GetGeoInfo(myGEO, GEO_ISO2, buffer, sizeOfBuffer, 0);
wcout<<buffer;
```

Thanks to @Christophe and @Thomas.

Comment: I think the last 2 lines should be `WCHAR* buffer = new WCHAR[sizeOfBuffer];
    int result = GetGeoInfoW(myGEO, GEO_ISO2, (LPWSTR)buffer, sizeOfBuffer, 0);` if you want to use WCHAR